# How to turn off sound effect for plugging in power source on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, power-management

How can I turn off the sound made when a power source is plugged in?

**Settings > Sounds > Sound effects > Alert volume** does not help

Comment: you can simply rename the file name which sits in /usr/share/sounds/....sub directories.. sound file names are pretty clear inside the sub directories ..

Comment: Example Pics from Ubuntu 19.10 https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWdJj.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR0Gq.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

First you have to find out if you have any specific sound theme running (In my case Ubuntu shipped with "Yaru"). To find this out run the following command:

> gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name

After that navigate to the following folder:

> /usr/share/sounds/${theme-name}/stereo

(In my case /usr/share/sounds/Yaru/stereo)

In this folder are two files `power-plug.oga` and `power-unplug.oga`.

Just delete rename these files to something else (e.g. `sudo mv power-plug.oga power-plug_disabled.oga`)

After this you have to do same again in the following folder because Ubuntu will use the `power-plug.oga` and `power-unplug.oga` files from this folder as a fallback:

> /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo

(this folder could also be named `/usr/share/sounds/ubunutu/stereo` depending on your Ubuntu version)

All done :D