# Please help me remove power plug and unplug sound from ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: sound, power-management

Due to some issue my charger getting connected and disconnected continuously and for each such action sound from system irritating me and I cannot attend meetings as everyone irritates with the noise I bring to the meeting :). I cannot change laptop right away as I have lot of data to backup. Just disabling that plug/unplug sound would do the job and I can continue for a while

Comment: I had the same problem and posted my solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1488928/1715509

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any particular method to remove *just* the sound for a single system action, but there are two options that might work for you:

**1 Mute System Sounds**

Open Settings and go to "Sounds", then change the "System Sounds" value to zero by moving the slider all the way to the left.

[image: Sound Settings]

**2 Do Not Disturb**

What I generally do during meetings, in person or online, is put my device into Do Not Disturb mode. This allows me to continue to have the sounds I want while the distractions are pushed off to the side.

[image: Do Not Disturb Toggle]

Hopefully one of these two options will accomplish your goal ...

Comment: Ssorry Both didn't work for me